# Show or hide table row if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, show-hide

I want to hide a table row (with input fields inside) when a checkbox is checked.
I found something that works:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr id="row">
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">Hide inputs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkbox').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
            $('#row').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('#row').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ge9zusk/1/)

But this only works if the checkbox is not checked already. So if the checkbox is checked at the beginning, I want the table row to be hidden. How do I do this?

*Please note that I don't know much about JavaScript, but I really need this*

Comment: This type of question has been asked here so many times already...

Comment: @ChristopherW - Apparently Google is a lost art.

Comment: @jalynn2 Apparently search features in general

Answer (score 5, accepted):

trigger [.change()](http://jqapi.com/#p=change) event after you attach events:

```
$(function () {
    $('#checkbox1, #checkbox2').change(function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr').prev();

        if (!this.checked)
            row.fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            row.fadeOut('slow');

    }).change();
});
```

Note: I make code shorter.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ge9zusk/5/)**

Answer (score 4):

Just call the change event after you initially register it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkbox').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
            $('#row').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('#row').fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $('#checkbox').change();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Musefan's answer is excelent, but following is also another way!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
($('#checkbox').prop('checked')==true) ? $('#row').fadeOut('slow'):$('#row').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#checkbox').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
            $('#row').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('#row').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you were looking for:

```js
$(function() {
  var init = true;
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      if (init) {
        $(this).prev().hide();
        init = false;
      } else $(this).prev().slideUp();
    } else $(this).prev().slideDown();
  }).change();
});
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Shown" />
  <input type="checkbox" />Hide input
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Hidden" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>Hide input
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic solution without hardcoded ids:

```js
$('table :checkbox').change(function(e, speed) {
    speed = typeof speed == 'undefined' ? 'slow' : 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').prev()[this.checked ? 'fadeOut' : 'fadeIn'](speed);
}).trigger('change', [0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">Hide inputs</td>
    </tr>
        
    <tr id="row2">
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" checked>Hide inputs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

just call the change function in document.ready after it

```
 $('#checkbox').change();
```

Like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#checkbox').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) $('#row').fadeIn('slow');
        else $('#row').fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $('#checkbox').change();
});
```

Here is the [**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1n70t03g/)

Answer (score 0):

you can initially hide them if you really want the checkbox to be checked initially.

```
<table>
<tr id="row" style="display: none;">
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked>Hide inputs</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#checkbox').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) 
        $('#row').fadeIn('slow');
    else 
        $('#row').fadeOut('slow');
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var showOrHideRow=fucntion(isChecked){
   if (isChecked) 
            $('#row').fadeOut('slow');
        else 
            $('#row').fadeIn('slow');
};

$(document).ready(function () {
showOrHideRow($('#checkbox').is(":checked"));

    $('#checkbox').change(function () {
        showOrHideRow(this.checked);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#tbl_name tr').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').show();
$('#tbl_name tr').find('input:checkbox:Unchecked').closest('tr').hide();