# Grouping the values inside a for-each loop using XSLT1.0

Tags: html, xslt-1.0

I have a table template something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="DisplaySortedData">
    <xsl:for-each select="$customer/id">        
        <xsl:call-template name="DisplayData" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The above code usually displays all the customers, and inside the `DisplayData` or `DisplayDataOnDropdown` template is where the `<TBODY>` is constructed. However, I now want to group only these customer ids (in real-life, this is a data from a config file so it is configurable. I just presented it as a variable):

```
<xsl:variable name="vipList" select="'1001|1002|1003|1004|1005|1006|1007|1008|1009|1010|1011|1012'"/>
```

Then if not in the VIP ids, display as a usual row (without dropdown) or another dropdown for not vips - whichever is easier.

The table output is something similar to the samples below (which is a dropdown table):

[Show or hide table row if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621174/show-or-hide-table-row-if-checkbox-is-checked)

or more like this:

https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/gaGBZz

My current code just displays a dropdown on each of the VIP ids, and does NOT group them all together.

```
<xsl:template name="DisplaySortedData">
    <xsl:variable name="vipList" select="'1001|1002|1003|1004|1005|1006|1007|1008|1009|1010|1011|1012'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="OptimizedIDs" select="'true'"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$customer/id">
        <xsl:variable name="custID" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$OptimizedIDs='true' and contains(concat('|',$vipList,'|'),concat('|',$custID,'|'))">
                <xsl:call-template name="DisplayDataAsDropdown" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="DisplayData" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I think my problem is just the logic of my for-each loop? I'm relatively new on XSL and I would really appreciate even a sample idea of a loop that does this.

Comment: is [javascript] at all relevant?

Comment: Yes, it's the for-each that will iterate over the customers and dictate their order of appearance. My XSLT is rusty but I think you should do two for-each loops, a first one handling only the VIPs and a second handling only the non-VIPs

Comment: @JaromandaX I think not... it's just that I used javascript and html to hide/show the table. I'll remove the tag. Apologies for the confusion. Cheers!

Comment: all good, was just asking :p

Comment: @Aaron Ohh... I see. Looks like a good suggestion. I'll try to code it and let's see how it goes...